# Which is better to put the Coroutine call in the Repository or the ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-room, coroutine

Just wondering others opinion I have 2 ways I can go about doing something and was curious which is better (and hopefully why you think so)

I have 2 files WordRepository and WordViewModel.  I can either do the coroutines in the Repo or in the ViewModel both ways work, but hoping someone can give me a clue as to why I would do the coroutines in one or the other and vice versa.

Version A.(Where the coroutine is in the Repo)

```
WordRepo:

class WordRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao): WordRepo {

    @WorkerThread
    override suspend fun deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays: Int): Int = withContext(IO) {
        return@withContext wordDao.deleteAll()
    }

}

WordViewModel:

class WordViewModel(private val wordRepository: WordRepo) : ViewModel() {

    fun deleteAllLogsOlderThanA(XDays:Int): Int = runBlocking {
        wordRepository.deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays)
    }

}
```

Version B.(Where the coroutine is in the ViewModel)

```
Word Repo:
class WordRepository(private val wordDao: WordDao): WordRepo {

    @WorkerThread
    override suspend fun deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays: Int): Int = wordDao.deleteAll()

}

WordViewModel:
class WordViewModel(private val wordRepository: WordRepo) : ViewModel() {

    fun deleteAllLogsOlderThanA(XDays:Int): Int = runBlocking {
            withContext(IO) {
                wordRepository.deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays)
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: `runBlocking` blocks the current thread, are you sure you want to use it?

Comment: how else do I call withContext and get a response cant use launch as it returns a job?

Comment: `launch` is used to start a non-blocking coroutine. You can create a function that wraps `launch` call and returns `Unit` if you don't want your function returns `Job`.

Comment: Ok but what if I want to return Int?

Comment: Using coroutines you can't return a value without blocking a thread. If you have `MutableLiveData` object in `ViewModel` you can use it to update UI: `launch { liveData.value = wordRepository.deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays)}`

Comment: Ok so the solution is to change the WordViewModel to be suspending and work up the chain so that the object that calls this function runs in its own custom scope or GlobalScope as the response is not needed outside the function call.

as I am calling it from the Application main.

Comment: So the repo has this

`@WorkerThread
override suspend fun deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays: Int): Int = wordDao.deleteAll()`

The wordViewModel has
`suspend fun deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays:Int): Int = wordRepository.deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays)`

and then the Log Object calls this
`suspend fun purgeOldLogsGreaterThan(XDays: Int): Int {
        return wordViewModel.deleteAllLogsOlderThan(XDays)
}`

and then called from the application
`GlobalScope.launch {
          Log.i("Log", "Purging ${LogA.purgeOldLogsGreaterThan(xDays)} logs which where older than $xDays old")
            }`

Comment: I prefer launching a coroutine in `ViewModel` or `Presenter`, using a local scope. So that a coroutine is started in `WordViewModel`'s `deleteAllLogsOlderThanA` function

Comment: Right, but in this case, the call to the database is completely self-contained not needing to access the ViewModel or anything.  Basically a Run and Forget.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think either way is fine honestly but if I have to choose I prefer keeping thread related code in the repository layer. (*Version A* in the example)

My justification:

(A) View Models should not assume how Repositories internally work. *Version B* implies that the View Model assumes that the Repository will run on the calling thread.

(B) Also, the repository should not depend on other components to use a specific thread to call its method. The repository should be complete by itself.

(C) To avoid code duplication. Having multiple View models calling one repository method is a very common situation. *Version A* wins in this case because you only need `Corountine` in one place, the repository.

I suggest looking at some of the Google Samples to see where they like to handle `Coroutine` and data access threading codes.

1. [Sunflower](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/data/GardenPlantingRepository.kt) uses `Coroutine` code in their repository. This is probably particularly useful for you because it includes examples of fire-and-forget type of requests.
2. [GitHubBrowserRepo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/RepoRepository.kt) does not use `Coroutine` but the repository keeps reference to the `Executor` instances that are used when accessing the data.

Comment: Thank you :) I was thinking Version A but my main reason was your C only so the other reasons are very helpful.  I will definitely check out the 2 google sample projects.

Comment: Where should I create a Coroutine Job then? in viewmodel or in repository? When should i clear in order to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: If you are using Android `ViewModel`, you can create jobs in viewmodel and clear jobs in [ViewModel#onCleared](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel#oncleared)

Comment: To the (A): Version B assumes that that the repository is on the running thread, but Version A assumes that it's on a worker thread. Which is worse?

Comment: @Malachiasz In version A, ViewModel does not know that repository runs on a worker thread. You could copy-paste ViewModels of Version B to Version A and it may still work. The reverse will likely fail.

Comment: I take your argument. Switched dispatcher somewhere at the beginning of the call chain doesn't assure that it's not switched again somewhere deeper. In other words the langue does not provide a possibility for the caller to bind called method to a given dispatcher. Except by a fragile custom.

Comment: What about the pagination library? Is it possible to execute the network call inside the repository and use it in the data source?

Comment: I cannot think of any reason that would make it not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The question is where to specify that repository jobs should run on IO threads pools:

- A) In Repository
- B) In ViewModel

Frankly I am not sure which way is better.

B) Having it in ViewModel means more transparency of what runs on which thread. This is also the way I mostly worked with RxJava. As a negative your ViewModel will be cluttered with thread switching (withContext()), while it's actually obvious that all repository job should run on the background thread. So is this extra information any useful?

A) Having it in Repository means more flexibility regarding thread switching in repository and cleaner code in ViewModel. Code will be less explicit from ViewModel point of view about threads. As a negative all repository methods will need to be suspended, so thus usable only from coroutines.